# Find the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

So far I have that $B = \{1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{3}\sqrt{5}\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$.

I think the discriminant of $B$ is $2^83^25^2$, which implies that, if $B$ is not an integral basis, then there is an algebraic integer of the form $\frac{1}{p}(a + b\sqrt{3} + c\sqrt{5} + d\sqrt{3}\sqrt{5})$ for integers $0 \leq a,b,c,d \leq p-1$ and $p$ one of $2,3,5$.

Beyond this, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299710/on-the-ring-of-integers-of-a-compositum-of-number-fields) for the discriminant of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{m},\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score 5):

The formula for the discriminant of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{m},\sqrt{n})$ is given in Theorem $3$ of the paper [Integers of biquadratic fields](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/033.pdf), page $525$. Theorem $2$ lists the integral bases for each case. Since $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{15})$ we are in the case $(3,3)\bmod 4$.